# Docusign Embedded Signing URL Demo Account No Longer Working

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the embedded signing API using JSON requests to create online signing sessions in the browsers.

The demo docusign signing URL's returned by Docusign are no longer working. We are testing the signing sessions again after a while.

Following is a sample signing [URL that is returned and is no longer working](https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=0dee4611-351d-4ade-9937-d3dec5c87467).

Can you please let look into this. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi Docusign Team, Can you let us know what the issue might be, we are no longer able to open the signing sessions in the browser for the signing urls created using the Docusign REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue is, The Integrator Key we were using is no longer working in the Demo Environment.

Generated a new Integrator Key in the Demo Environment and we are able to create valid signing URL's.

Question again - 
1. Is there a validity period for the Integrator Key's?
2. Does the Integrator Key become invalid after a certain amount of time, once the Demo account configuration is moved to Docusign Production?.

Thank You.

Comment: Strange, now the Original Integrator Key has started to work. Generating a new Demo key might have refreshed something as we did not use the old integrator key for a while.

Comment: I can only think this must have been a bug on DocuSign's side or some other sort of hiccup.  Integrator Keys should always be valid in the demo environment, and once promoted to production then that particular key also works in production then...

Answer (score 0):

From the [DocuSign Dev Center page that explains Embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign):

```
URL tokens have a TTL (time to life) and are only valid for 5 minutes at the time of this writing. New tokens need to be generated upon expiration.
```

So, if it's been more than 5 minutes since you retrieved the URL by issuing a "Get Recipient View" request, then it's expected that the URL will no longer work (i.e., will no longer launch the recipient's signing session).  The embedded signing feature is designed such that you should not issue the "Get Recipient View" request until the signer has indicated (in your application, perhaps by clicking a button or link) that they are ready to sign. You should never be caching/saving the URL for later use, because it won't work beyond 5 minutes from the time of issue.

Comment: Thanks Kim but we are aware of this as we have been using the API for the past year but our issue is something different. The API URL's are no longer working in DEMO environments, they are working in PROD Docusign accounts. Basically the issue is the signing url's once opened are not retrieving any HTML Content from Docusign.

Comment: I am unable to repro the issue you describe -- i.e., I just sucessfully created an Envelope in DEMO with an embedded/captive recipient, and then retrieved the recipient's signing URL with a "Get Recipient View" call,...that URL successfully launches the recipient's Envelope in DEMO.  I even tested with an 'old' (incomplete) Envelope that was created back in April -- same result: the URL retrieved with "Get Recipient View" operation successfully launches the Envelope.  Are you able to consistently repro the issue you describe?

Comment: Also note that each URL is for single-use only. If a URL is retrieved using the 'Get Recipient View' operation, and then subsequently used to launch the recipient's DocuSign envelope -- that same URL cannot be used to access the Envelope again, even if the 5-minute timeout hasn't occurred yet.